# Archive old rolled over logs in logback

Tags: java, logback, spring-logback

If I have an RollingFileAppender that creates 20MB log files everyday in new folder, how can I configure it to zip all that folders from last month?
Example logs tree:

```
.
├── current
|   └── 2019
|       └── 06
|           ├── 01
|           |   ├── application.0.log
|           |   └── application.1.log
|           ├── ...
|           └── 29
|               ├── application.0.log
|               └── application.1.log
└── archived
    ├── 2018
    |   ├── 01.zip
    |   ├── 02.zip
    |   ├── ...
    |   └── 12.zip
    └── 2019
        ├── 01.zip
        ├── ...
        ├── 04.zip
        └── 05.zip
```